# Update Application Feature in Android

Tags: android

I want to put update application feature in android.
can anyone tell me how to achive this functionality..?

thanks for reading

Comment: Please be more specific. Kindly provide as much details as possible so that people can help you more efficiently.

Comment: sure buddy...suppose i have uploaded my app in android  market,noe if i would add some new feature in my previous app.how would client get my updated app.

Comment: AFAIK, Google takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this; Market checks for, and alerts users about app updates automatically.